# geocodeAddressString is not running for the following address

Tags: ios, objective-c, geocoding

If i give any address for this method it is not at all calling.But if if give "1800 Ellis St,San Francisco, CA  94102,United States" it is being called. tell me what is wrong.

```
 [geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"#83 2nd Floor Diagonal Road V.V.Puram Bangalore 560004 India"
                     completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks1, NSError* error){
                         for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks1)
                         {
                             annotationCoord=  aPlacemark.location.coordinate;
                             [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
                             MKCoordinateRegion region;
                             region.center.latitude=annotationCoord.latitude;
                             region.center.longitude=annotationCoord.longitude;

                             region.span.longitudeDelta=0.;
                             region.span.latitudeDelta=0.;


                             self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
                             [self.mapView setRegion:region];
                             _annotation=[[LDAnnotation alloc]initWithCoordinate:annotationCoord andTitle:@""subTitle:@""];
                             [self.mapView addAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)_annotation];
                             [_searchAddressTF resignFirstResponder];
                         }
                     }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your placemarks1 array is probably empty, as you're not checking if it is or not, the block just isn't executing. This is the common format

```
[self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
```

you can try printing the size of the place marks. Check out this page if you haven't seen it already. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/forward-geocoding-with-clgeocoder--mobile-11011

Comment: yes it is empty. why it should be empty ?. it is one organization address. atleast it has to show nearest location right?

Comment: well no, it should have at least one place mark to store the address you're creating. place marks are how CoreLocation stores things like "country" "province" "street address" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/

Comment: as for why its empty... it must be that geocoder is failing to understand the address you're trying to create. I recommend if you know the coordinates of the address, try creating a a CLLocation from that and using reverse geocoder to see what place mark values it comes up with, and then try to match those when you do your forward geocoder.